# Winforms CL20R3 with CefSharp Project

Tags: c#, winforms, filenotfoundexception, cefsharp

I have a similar problem to this question [C# windows appication Event: CLR20r3 on application start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244694/c-sharp-windows-appication-event-clr20r3-on-application-start)

The error is like this:

> Application: MantenedorPlanesMain.exe
>       Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>       Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>       Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>       Battery:
>            in CefSharp.Example.CefExample.Init ()
>            in CefSharp.WinForms.Example.Program.Main ()

But only on some machines, for example, on my computer I can use the program without any problem and in a computer of my office too.

I tried to find the source of the problem here in stackoverflow and realized that the error was caused by a cs file not found, but is within the project.

When I go to see `CefSharp.WinForms.Example.Program.cs` and comment the line of `CefSharp.Example.CefExample.Init()` throws me the same error in another file.

I tried everything, even the `CopyLocal = true` and `x86`, but still not working. I think there may be a problem with the system language, which is the only common factor of the machines that worked, Spanish language system.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context `FileNotFoundException` usually means you need to install `VC++` or that you compiled in `Debug` mode (You need to build in `Release` mode when running on a machine without VS installed)

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/NuGet/Readme.txt#L18

Also See the `Note` within https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#6-how-do-i-include-the-visual-studio-c-2012-redistributables-on-the-target-app

Comment: Yes! The target machine need VC++ 2012 redist to work! thanks for the help, yesterday was a nightmare!