# CefSharp 3 WPF project didn't run in client machine

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, cefsharp

I need to run a CefSharp WPF project in a Client machine. The project works on development machine. But did not run in the Client machine.

Here are some findings which I found:

1. When I install the Visual Studio 2013 to client machine and run the application, it works perfectly.
2. Application did not run when install .NetFramework 4.5 and Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 redistributable x86 package to client machine

(As proposed by many developers in Stack Over Flow for same problem, I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 redistributable x86 package also. But it didn't work.)

I have included the following dll's to debug folder.

- CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll
- CefSharp.Core.dll
- CefSharp.dll
- CefSharp.Example.dll
- CefSharp.Wpf.dll
- d3dcompiler_43.dll
- d3dcompiler_47.dll
- ffmpegsumo.dll
- GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll
- GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.dll
- GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform.dll
- icudt.dll
- libcef.dll
- libEGL.dll
- libGLESv2.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll
- msvcp110
- msvcr110
- vccorlib110
- pdf.dll

I included following files also to debug folder.

- locales folder
- cef.pak
- cef_100_percent.pak
- cef_200_percent.pak
- devtools_resources.pak
- icudtl.dat
- CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe

But no luck.

When I run the application It shows an error message as "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess has stopped working".

I searched the google as well as stackoverflow. But unable to find a solution.

Please find the debug log which I got from debug.txt file in the client machine,

> [0702/041548:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(148)]
>   0B1782D0: set chrome proxy config service to 0D3A2260
>   [0702/041548:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(277)]
>   0B1782D0: Done pushing proxy to UpdateProxyConfig
>   [0702/041551:VERBOSE1:webrtc_internals.cc(55)] Could not get the
>   download directory. [0702/041601:VERBOSE1:statistics_recorder.cc(294)]
>   Collections of all histograms Histogram: AsyncDNS.ConfigChange
>   recorded 1 samples, average = 1.0 (flags = 0x1)

Can anyone know how to solve this problem? If yes, please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a reference to `CefSharp.Example.dll`, did you build from `source`? What version are you using?

See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31175760/4583726

Comment: Cef.Initialize() has a performDependencyCheck flag you can set to true. Does that return an error if you turn it on?

Comment: @amaitland I have compiled it again in release mode and got the same issue. I'm building the application from source and I'm using CefSharp 3, (Assembly Version 41.0.0)

Comment: @Yoshi I have set performDependecyCheck to true. It didn't return any error. Application works in development machine. But no luck in client machine.

Comment: If you built `CefSharp` from source using `VS2013`, then you'll need `VC++ 2013`, they're linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solve the issue. As most of the developer said, we need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 redistributable x86 package as well as relevant dll's (See question for details). The mistake which I did was, I included the dll's which are in the Debug Folder. But if we run the application in release mode we need to include the dll's which are in release folder. Dll's in the Debug folder and Release folder are not same. I hope this will help to someone else in future.

Comment: install vc++ 2012 on the development pc or on the runtime environment?