# WebBrowser control embedded with Chromium not working on Win32 tablet (Windows 8)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, cefsharp

I am using  WebBrowser Control embedded with Chromium using CEFSharp 3.0 in my WPF application. I works fine on windows 7 and Windows 8 but the same executable is not even opening on WinRT device. I am actually trying to run WPF application on Win32 tablet.  It is not a WPF application and not a metro app.

I have read some blogs which says that WinRT/win8 tablets devices does not support third party browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, Mozilla etc. I need to use Chrome to improve the performance of my webpage.

Is there a solution to my query ? Any other alternative is also appreciated. 
Please help!!

Comment: Only Windows Store Apps will run on Windows RT. No desktop apps.

Comment: @Clemens sorry clemens it is Win32(Windows 8 Pro) tablet and not WinRT. but the problem remains same. I ported the win32 exe many times on tablet, but when I use Chrome browser it is not even opening the exe. Any clue ..

Comment: What's the error message? Have you installed `VC++ 2012`? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184802/cefsharp-3-wpf-project-didnt-run-in-client-machine for the most common problem deploying to a client machine.

Comment: What version of `CefSharp` are you using specifically? Did you compile from source or use a `nuget` package?

Comment: @amaitland thank you soo much. Installing VC++ 2012 solved the problem right away. Please post the same so that I can mark it as answer. :)