# C# Winforms application fails to start up after installing it using Setup Project

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, dllnotfoundexception

When I run the shortcut after Setup Project Deployment Installation, I got the following error and the application did not launch.

I am creating a Windows Application using Winforms (C#). I even compiled it in release mode but still got the error.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: sendmail.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 536482de
  Problem Signature 04: System.Data.SQLite
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.92.0
  Problem Signature 06: 532a0415
  Problem Signature 07: 124
  Problem Signature 08: 1d
  Problem Signature 09: System.DllNotFoundException
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

**EDIT 1:**

I am working with c#, windows form.

I have added the following references:

1. EntityFramework.dll
2. EntityFrameworkServer.dll
3. System.Data.Sqlite.dll
4. System.Data.Sqlite.EF6.dll
5. System.Data.Sqlite.Linq.dll

The error occurs when I test on my system itself.

Comment: SqlLite dll missing. Isn't the error clear?

Comment: If an assembly is missing, make sure that the installer includes all of the required (referenced) assemblies. Each assembly you referenced must be available in the install.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a version of Sqlite that does not embed VC++ runtime inside it? If yes, you will need to install VC++ on the test machine.

Is there any dlls (present in your output folder) that are missing on the test machine in the folder created  by your setup?

Comment: I am working with c#, windows form , i have added entityframework.dllntityframeworkserver.dll, system.data.sqlite.dll,system.data.sqlite.EF6.dll,system.data.sqlite.Linq.dll, error occurs , when itest in my system itself

Comment: Does your WinForm application launch successfully if you just compile it and launch it from your output folder by double clicking it? If yes, can you check if your setup deployment is deploying all the dlls that you mentioned above in the installation folder

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the DLLs are in the same Directory as the assembly. Set  [CopyLocal=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167395/visual-studio-copy-local) in the properties of each refferenced DLL.

Comment: I have changed all dll to copyLocal=true , even error continues

Answer (score 0):

I also met exactly same problem. My program also worked properly when debugging but after I build the installer and try to install to my computer, this error happened.

I decided to compare my Application folder in the Program Files and my Debug folder. I discovered that the package project didn't copy two folders x64 and x86 which contain the "SQLite.Interop.dll" file.
I copied it from my Debug folder to the Application folder in Program Files and I worked like a charm.

So I fixed by adding that DLL folder to the Application Folder in the Package Project like in the below picture.

[image: Package Project]